# How to access the subdomain of an IP address in the browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, web, ip, ip-address

To get to the IP address of an example website, you just visit

```
subdomain.example.com
```

However, if I try to visit

```
subdomain.2.1.33.111 (example ip)
```

Firefox returns an error.
Why?

Comment: One possible workaround is to use [xip.io](http://xip.io) per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370422).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

An IP address with a subdomain is not a valid statement - an IP address is not a domain, thus it cannot have a subdomain. It is not possible without DNS.

All browsers will return an error for this. The reason is that subdomains are part of the DNS (Domain Name Service) system, where IP addresses are related to the underlying IP protocol.

The best way to think of this relationship is that domains (including subdomains) are human-readable labels which DNS then allows you to point to IP addresses. It would not be very catchy to have an IP address as your website on a TV ad, for example.

There is much more detail on [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) and [IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) if you want to delve into more detail than this.

Comment: The information is good however the main question was still not answered "How to access the subdomain of an IP address in the browser?"; does this mean we cannot access a subdomain without using a DNS?

Comment: It should answer the question in that saying that an IP address has a subdomain is not a valid statement - an IP address is not a domain, thus it cannot have a subdomain. To be clear: it is not possible without DNS.

Answer (score 17):

IP addresses don't support subdomains. If your goal is to serve several application on server without an assigned domain, the best way is to use ports:

```
2.1.33.111:8080
```

Some ports may already be in use or blocked for security reasons. If you need a list of some recommended ports, you could try using the same ones that Cloudflare [supports](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/network-ports/).

**HTTP:**

- 80
- 8080
- 8880
- 2052
- 2082
- 2086
- 2095

**HTTPS:**

- 443
- 2053
- 2083
- 2087
- 2096
- 8443

Comment: How would you go about using ports for this ? I have tried using ports in this way and fails to connect

Comment: @ib95 You need to make sure your web server is listening to ports other than 80 (and 443).

Answer (score 13):

This isn't possible via firefox. However a work around is to edit your OS *hosts* file see: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29).

Create or edit and add a line like:

192.168.1.100 subdomain.example.com

Remember to remove the line when you're done!

Answer (score 6):

You can't mix a subdomain (DNS name) with an IP (no DNS name)

Try to use /etc/hosts file. For instance:

```
# IP  Hotsname    
2.1.33.111     subdomain.example.com
```

For Firefox It's ok but Chrome resolves names in a fancy way.

Answer (score 2):

A hostname is a domain (or subdomain) name that has at least one associated IP address.

The associated IP address to a domain name might differ for subdomains.

You can get the associated IP address of a domain (or subdomain) with `nslookup`.

Try `nslookup example.com` vs. `nslookup subdomain.example.com` to see the difference.

If firefox (or other browsers) you can either enter the hostname (e.g. example.com or subdomain.example.com) or the IP address (e.g. 11.22.33.44).