# Why is xip io needed when I can access the IP directly?

Tags: dns, xip.io

xip.io welcome screens says this :

> 10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1

Why do we need to go through xip io when I can directly use the IP?

Is it used to access servers by domain name instead of IP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166205/cant-seem-to-access-xip-io-url-from-my-iphone-when-running-rails-app-with-pow#comment84801209_26166205 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/35991630/470749 are interesting questions about xip.io too.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The main use case is when your application needs to support multiple subdomains.

Take for example these production subdomains:

- www.example.com
- admin.example.com
- members.example.com

Or you can consider a multi-tenant application where each account gets its own custom subdomain:

- mycompany.example.com
- anotherguy.example.com

So it's easy enough to setup a production environment to serve this requests.

But without a service like xip.io for your development environment, you cannot put a subdomain in front of an IP address to route your request appropriately.

To get around this, you can access your application through a subdomain like this through xip.io:

```
http://mycompany.10.0.0.1.xip.io/
```

As xip.io states, this then works flawlessly if you're trying to access the application from other machines on your local network, be they smartphones, tablets, other OSes within VMs, etc.

Comment: Thanks Chris. This, in conjunction with name-based virtual hosting, makes perfect sense.

Comment: @user6317694 You're welcome. I suppose it makes sense for virtual hosting if you don't want the extra step of setting up a local DNS mapping to a local site. But I'm finding that the wildcard subdomain is the killer feature.

Comment: (Especially when considering the need to test on smartphones, etc.)

Comment: Clears out why WordPress Multisite AMI by Bitnami on AWS does this and not on the simple WP install.

Comment: If your website refers to its assets via domain name, you will not be able to resolve the urls for those assets and they will trigger 404 and display a broken website